# Jenkins with Ansible: SSH doesn't work, but manual does

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, ansible

i have installed jenkins-docker-container on my synology.
After that I installed the jenkins-ansible-plugin, installed ansible in the docker container (apt-get install ansible) (as user root) and specified the path (/use/bin/) of the ansible installation under "tools"-"ansible-installation".

In my jenkinsfile I start ansible like this:

```
def run_ansible() {
    ansiblePlaybook(
        inventory: "${env.ANSIBLE_INVENTORY}",
        credentialsId: "${env.ANSIBLE_CREDENTIALSID}",
        colorized: true,
        vaultCredentialsId: "${env.ANSIBLE_VAULTCREDENTIALSID}",
        disableHostKeyChecking: true,
        playbook: 'playbooks/1.0_all.yml',
        extras: """
                -e backup_external_dependencies=${params.backup_external_dependencies}
                -vvv
                """,
    )
}
```

**The pipeline stops when trying to establish the SSH connection:**

```
19:25:41  <raspberry3b> Attempting python interpreter discovery
19:25:41  <192.168.220.10> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
19:25:41  <192.168.220.10> SSH: EXEC ssh -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/ssh2988863641993845403.key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=120 -o 'ControlPath="/tmp/.ansible/cp/fe06d3d81b"' 192.168.220.10 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.11'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.10'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.9'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.8'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Ansible remains in this state without aborting.
If I then go into the docker container - in the jenkins workspace - I can see the temporary files for the SSH connection. (key, password for the key)
When I copy the SSH command from the GUI and execute it in the docker container I am asked for the password for the SSH key. If I then use the password from the temporary files and insert it, the ssh connection to the target host is established.

```
root@jenkins:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test# ls -la
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   286 Sep 14 15:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins    24 Sep 13 19:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   158 Sep 14 15:41 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins     8 Sep 13 19:22 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  5342 Sep 14 15:41 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 19881 Sep 14 15:41 ansible.cfg
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins    30 Sep 14 15:41 inventories
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   172 Sep 14 15:41 playbooks
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   650 Sep 14 15:41 roles
-r-------- 1 jenkins jenkins   465 Sep 14 15:41 ssh4608831987304154403.key
-rwx------ 1 jenkins jenkins    87 Sep 14 15:41 ssh6885927636002023764.sh
-r-------- 1 jenkins jenkins   128 Sep 14 15:41 vault3206200489256772372.password
```

If I run ansible on my windows host via WSL and the same SSH key / user, everything works as well.

Here is my ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
inventory      = ./inventories/hosts
library        = ./ansible_modules
gather_timeout = 120
roles_path    = ./roles:./roles/external-roles
host_key_checking = False
stdout_callback = yaml
timeout = 120
remote_user = ansible
ansible_managed = Ansible managed: {file} modified on %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S by {uid} on {host}
retry_files_enabled = False

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
control_path_dir = /tmp/.ansible/cp
pipelining = true
scp_if_ssh = smart
transfer_method = smart
retries = 6

[persistent_connection]
connect_timeout = 120
connect_retry_timeout = 120
command_timeout = 120

[accelerate]
accelerate_timeout = 120
accelerate_connect_timeout = 30.0
accelerate_daemon_timeout = 120
```

I hope you can help me. I have the feeling that this is just a small thing that prevents Ansible from successfully establishing the SSH connection. Thanks!!